# Survey: English translations of the Nicene Creed

Tags: denomination-survey, nicene-creed, chrestomathy-request

Someone posted a question recently asking about the use, in the Nicene Creed, of the phrase "true God from true God".

This was mildly surprising, as the version *I* learned uses "very God of very God". Upon some further poking about, I've noticed it appears some versions use "eternally begotten", while others use "begotten ... before all worlds".

So, I'm curious... what textual differences exist in various (English) translations of the NC, and what denominations use which versions?

p.s. Please refrain from critiquing why you like or dislike a particular translation. This is just a survey of what variations *exist* and who uses which.

Comment: *Verily* means *truly*, and *verity* means *truth*; hence, [very](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/very#English).

Comment: @Lucian, I'm not claiming that different translations have different *meanings*. I'm just curious how many *exist*. Consider, for example, someone who knows the KJV Lord's Prayer trying to say it with a congregation that uses a more modern translation... that person might have some difficulty!

Comment: Finally, another thing I can tag [tag:crestomathy-request]!

Comment: I have asked a question on [Stack Exchange - English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574922/do-verity-and-verily-derive-from-very) in regard to the derivation of 'very' (does it mean 'truly', in its original concept ?).

Comment: This seems to be a fairly in-depth page on the different English language versions of the NC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_versions_of_the_Nicene_Creed